# Custom menu for chrome text field

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a custom pop-up menu, which appears when the user focuses a text field. In this menu, the user should be able to click on buttons or something.

I tried using *content scripts*, but my problem is, that I don't find good events to show and hide the menu.

I tried the `focus` event to show the menu and the `blur` event to hide the menu, but obviously when selecting something *in* the menu, the text field looses focus and `blur` fires, which hides the menu and does not process the click. Additionally, when I use the focus and blur events on text fields, I guess I will override existing event of the webpage.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: It's very tricky as to my knowledge content scripts don't allow you to sandbox the events specific to your extension from the routine functionality of the page. There will always be contention over event handling, it can be mostly circumvented for specific pages where you are familiar with the events, but if the extension is designed for the whole web it will be near impossible to handle all the different scenarios. Sorry for the pessimism, maybe others can suggest a good workaround here?

Comment: Isn't there a way to use chrome UI elements instead of DOM elements for realizing this?